# Android 11, keyboard bottom area is not working after app launched via Custom launcher and then back from app Recent List

Tags: android, android-11, android-launcher, android-gesture

In Android-11, I enabled the Gesture navigation in the Android System Settings and launched a sample application(which contains only one editText on the Screen) using my custom App Launcher. you can see in the below screenshot,

Gesture Navigation means there is no 3-button navigation, similar behavior of iPhones behavior,

[image: img1]

You can see in the above image at the keyboard bottom, that there is some additional space available, so in order to remove the space, I used the below code to hide that

```
 WindowInsetsController wcon = getWindow().getInsetsController();
 wcon.hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
 wcon.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
```

So, after I used the code, I got the expected behavior as below, in this stage everything is working fine, (the additional area is hided)

[image: img2]

But,

Once I moved this from recent apps like below and again moved back from the normal stage, the **Bottom keyboard area touch is not working**, I highlight using the Red Color,

> **This only happens, when I launched the app using Custom App**

[image: img3]

What went wrong with this behavior, Why is the bottom area not working?

Comment: Don't change the insets.  Keyboards manage their own insets.  Changing them can do all sorts of weird things.  Keyboards actually have 3 insets-  one of them is the touchable area of the keyboard.  Most likely you confused the system so that the visible insets were changed but the touchable ones weren't.

Comment: Thanks, @GabeSechan for your kindly reply, but this works, when I used to launch the application in the default android launcher, I haven't faced any issue but this will only be appearing when I used my custom App Laucher, and moreover especially back from recent app list, any luck on that?